# How to explode geometry in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, dissolve

I have got two geometries one is polygons (postcode boundaries) and second is linestring (roads). I want to intersect them together and want roads that are intersecting the polygons. While doing this I got that many sections of roads are  still connected to each other (dissolved). So I want to separate them (explode) as they are in geometry. I did search for the solution but haven't found anything.

This is the case below they all are a one feature in QGIS. I want them as single entity.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`st_dump()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) to transform multi-parts to single-parts

```
SELECT sometable.field1, sometable.field2,
      (ST_Dump(sometable.the_geom)).geom AS the_geom
FROM sometable;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I have run this query. Result is not just satisfactory, Still the same problem.

Comment: @Shobhit what do you mean? st_dump is the tool to explode a multi-part to single parts, which is what you have asked... Clarify the question if you want something else

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.
Like in the photo uploaded their are three links which have a common field i.e. RoadName.
I have clipped this Road data with post code boundary but the road segments are still connected due the same name.

So I just simply want to separate them as single feature. So that if you select a feature that will show you just one feature not others.

Comment: @Shobhit and what is wrong with applying st_dump on the clip output?

Comment: It is actually not exploding the geometries. So I have run another method, ST_Union, ST_Multi and then ST_Dump.

Because it was not exploding so Merged them then break all of them. I am pretty sure there would be another better method but it worked for me.

SELECT sometable.field1, sometable.field2,
     (ST_Dump(St_multi(ST_Union(sometable.the_geom)))).geom AS the_geom

FROM sometable
Group By sometable.field1, sometable.field2,;

Thanks JGH at least you came forward for help. :)